# npm start in VS code react project doesn't work

Tags: node.js, reactjs, dependencies

I'm getting this err after I start my react project. I tried all mentioned solutions in previous posts, including all 7 steps but can't solve it. Can anyone help please?
Thanks,

```
enter code here
```

There might be a problem with the project dependency tree.
It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.

The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

"webpack": "4.44.2"

Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of webpack was detected higher up in the tree:

C:\Users\mirja\node_modules\webpack (version: 5.47.0)

Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause hard-to-debug issues.

If you would prefer to ignore this check, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That will permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.

To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact order:

1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
3. Remove "webpack" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.

In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem.
If this has not helped, there are a few other things you can try:

5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
   This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.
6. Check if C:\Users\mirja\node_modules\webpack is outside your project directory.
   For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.
7. Try running npm ls webpack in your project folder.
   This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed webpack.

If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That would permanently disable this preflight check in case you want to proceed anyway.

P.S. We know this message is long but please read the steps above :-) We hope you find them helpful!

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! space-x@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the space-x@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

Comment: Well, have you tried the steps above? Did they work?

Comment: Hey, thank you for response, and yes, I made it :))))) I deleted webpack from node_modules on my :C and now it works. I still have no clue why did it happen? This was my 10th project and first such kind error....

Comment: Could you please accept my answer, because then this thread will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, with this amount of dependencies from time to time a lockup happens. The best way is to simply delete node_modules  and make a clean npm install. npm will figure out the problem and fix it most of the time.

Comment: Aha, thank you for your answer, so I make clean npm install with simply " npm install" in VS terminal?